# is there any specific function to bring value to a selected cell without vlookup?

Tags: excel, vlookup, xlookup, index-match

knowing only date, time, and DRND code (starting TP and numbers), and amount, can i bring the card code to a next to a cell from a different sheet?[image: this is the sheet i want to bring a card number]
and
[image: card numbers]

I was trying to do this
[!could not do vlookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHfAH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHfAH.png)
both sheets has tp numbers, but second sheet which contains card number , u can see the tp over or under the row, so i cant find the right formula to bring the card numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the 'vlookup' (or 'index match') to do the match you are already trying and then define that you want the previous row. Something like this, applied to the correct rows in your file:

INDEX(E:E,MATCH(B3,D:D,0)**-1**)

Note the **"-1"** which is the condition that defines that you always want the previous row.

Comment: Which E:E Which D? can you please elaborate?

Comment: E:E is the return array, so it should be the column where the credit card number is. D:D is the lookup array, so it must be the column where "TPXX" is located. B3 is the lookup value, which corresponds to one of the cells you want on the first sheet.